# Get screen field values from a JAVA application with user32.dll C#

Tags: c#, user32

This is my scenario, I have an application and I would like to get its fields value using user32.dll with C#, but the problem is that Spy++, WinInspector, any UI inspector are only able to see the window class and window caption, but not the fields that are inside the parent window. Then I said: "Ok I will query the window and get all children to see what happens and understand why I am not able to get any information about it".
What I found was a child with class name: "SunAwtToolKit", I suppose that this element will contain all the fields inside him, I figure out that is usually harder to deal with Java Applications to screen scraping.
My questions is, is there any other way to do it?Maybe I am looking at the wrong Windows API, what I would like to find is at least all the children handles.
Thank you very much for any help or suggestion :)

---

The program looks like (almost the same):

[image: Similar interface]

Has someone deal with fields like those here (Jtextfield) using user32.dll or any other technique?

Comment: Have you tried the official Microsoft tool Inspect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521.aspx ? If it doesn't work, you will have hard time, it may be just rendered (bitmap) text.

Comment: Hi Simon,
Thank you for your suggestion, I didn't know about this program, then I am installing SDK for Windows and I will see if it works, anyway, I'm almost 100% sure that is not rendered bitmap, as this is a normal application and have nothing to hide, even because there are fields that allow me to write and even those I am not able to get nothing, Thanks a lot I will let every knows my result soon. :)

Comment: Hi Simon, I just tried and I get the same as I get with my application... :(
Any other suggestion? thanks :)

Comment: Difficult to say without more information or the application itself, but it doesn't look good.

Comment: It seems that the class that contains everything is:
SunAwtToolKit, because if I open a new dialog inside the application I got a window with a frame inside called: SunAwtDialog, looking at that I could find that is something related with JAVA, then maybe there is another way to get its content and not thread it as a text field